# Having issue redirecting output to a file

Tags: linux, kubectl, minikube

When I run the below command in my terminal I get this message:

```
bash: nginx_deployment_status.yaml: Permission denied
```

However, when I run the command in `sudo` mode, i get this message:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

command:

```
kubectl get deployment nginx-deployment -o yaml > nginx_deployment_status.yaml
```

When I run `kubectl get deployment nginx-deployment -o yaml`, I get the output printed out on the terminal.

Also when I run the comaand:

```
echo test > nginx_deployment_status.yaml
```

I get the below message

```
bash: nginx_deployment_status.yaml: Permission denied
```

Comment: The first error ("permission denied") sounds as if you're just running the command from a directory to which you don't have write access. What is your current directory when you run the command? What are the permissions on it? If you run `sudo kubectl ...` it will no longer be looking at the correct configuration file (and using `sudo` won't help with errors caused by i/o redirection).

Comment: @larsks, I have write permission on my current directory from which I ran the command

Comment: Can you include in your question the exact text of the error message? And just for the sake of my sanity also include the result of running something like `echo test > nginx_deployment_status.yaml`?

Comment: @larsks, I have edited the Question, to include your suggestions

Comment: Those errors show pretty clearly that this is just a file permission error: either (a) you don't have write permissions on the directory you're in, or (b) the file `nginx_deployment_status.yaml` exists and you don't have write permissions to *that*. Either case can be verified by appropriate application of `ls -l`.

Comment: @larsks, thanks, I had to change the entire permission for user/owner, group and others to 777 (rwx) for it to work